# Delayed choice experiment for misaligned Mach-Zender interferometer

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, interferometry

In quantum Mach-Zender interference, a single photon can be prepared to have a 100 percent probability of traveling through a particular path (that classically would be a 50 percent chance). This can all be explained with unitary beam splitters interfering the quantum amplitudes. But I know experimentally that I can tilt a beam splitter at an angle such that we obtain 3 outputs: 1 aligned output that is the "proper" interference of the two inputs and 2 misaligned outputs in which the transmitted/reflected parts of the two inputs simply pass by each other. (as illustrated in my drawing)

[image]

If quantum interference occurs in the "proper" output, then all of the photons should go to the misaligned outputs- but in this direction there should be path distinguishability - which should cause the quantum interference of the "proper" output to disappear. This is a little bit perplexing because it suggests that even if one of the ports is completely aligned properly, it sort of mysteriously sees absolutely zero quantum interference.

Also, this is a fairly simple system - so is there a more mathematical way of expressing this using something density matrices (to describe how my state is being "mixed")?

Comment: I don't have my PhD in Physics, I'm a retired EE that reads a lot about quantum optics.  Mach-Zender is a great experiment and I think the explanation relies on the "photon wave function" theory, and it may answer your question above as well.  Probably you've studied the concept, the photon or instead we should say the wave function seems to be able to redefine itself at any time before collapse.

Answer (score 1):

If you were making a drawing with angles, you would immediately see that this is impossible: If the beams leave in the same direction at one port, the must do so at the other as well.

In fact, you can see that this is entirely impossible: A setup doing what you claim would take $3$ input modes $(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ (the third in the vaccum), and map them to
$$
O:\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\c_3\end{pmatrix}\mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}\gamma_1(c_1+c_2)+\alpha_1c_3\\
\gamma_2c_1+\alpha_2c_3\\\gamma_3c_2+\alpha_1c_3
\end{pmatrix}\ .
$$
You can easily see that there is no orthogonal (=linear optical) transformation doing that, since the first two columns of
$$
O\equiv\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma_1 & \gamma_1 & \alpha_1 \\
\gamma_2 & 0 & \alpha_2 \\
0 & \gamma_3 & \alpha_3 \end{pmatrix}
$$
are not orthogonal.

So whatever you are seeing in the lab, it must be something else with a more complicated description.  (One way to fix it would be e.g. to add additional output modes -- this would allow to make the first two columns orthogonal, but also e.g. erase the which-way information in the other path, or restore interference in two paths.)

Comment: I will spend some time to think about how this can happen theoretically, but I have seen this happen in a lab setting. Specifically with a standard [polarizing beam splitter](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=739) and a standard diode laser at 795nm.  I think the "missing" theoretical component might be that the light upon exiting the cube will receive a lateral displacement (since the birefringent material is encased in a glass cube), if the input beam is at an angle relative to the "normal" of the beamsplitter.

Comment: This lateral displacement shouldn't change the angles...but I think to compensate for this lateral displacement, you need to choose particular angles of the inputs of the beams and the bsplitter.

Comment: If this is possible, you should be able to write a transformation on the input modes which (i) is unitary and (ii) yields the correct 3 output modes.  Did you try that?  Otherwise my feeling is that you are just making claims without even trying to justify them.  (Surprised why this got a downvote - this is all I pointed out.)